# Maximum Data Set Size For MATLAB Mesh?

Tags: matlab, max, mesh

I am plotting a waveform as a function of time and space using a MATLAB mesh plot.  The number of space steps is 101.  The number of time steps is originally 2^14.  I get a good plot except for some wraparound of the signal at the window edges.  So I doubled my number of time steps to 2^15.  When I do this the plots return garbage.

Is there a maximum data set size for mesh plots in MATLAB? Is it depend on the version of MATLAB? Or is it machine dependent?

Comment: You do realize that the performance of step sizes are very dependent on the ODE/difference equation/your forward propagation methodology, etc and a blanket question like this cannot be answered... If you were to provide more details on that, someone might be able to answer it, but it would be off-topic here. I would suggest committing to the [Scientific computing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28815/computational-science?referrer=m32vrLj7gUCu25kobpt0GA2) proposal, which is set to launch after Thanksgiving. That might be a better home for it.

Comment: Thank you for the info on the scientific computing site.  I didn't change my step size.  Only doubled the range.  Do you not think it is a plotting limitation?

Comment: Oh I see. I though you increased sampling of your time. In any case, it is very dependent on the problem and I can't say much. Who knows, you might have a chaotic system that starts out well behaved but erupts into chaos abruptly. There are ways to study such problems, but I can't answer without additional info. I would recommend waiting for the new site

Answer (score 1):

Generally Matlab will happily create large matrices as long as your computer has enough memory and it is within the 32-bit or 64-bit addressing limits.  See http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1110.html

If you were hitting the memory cap you would get an out of memory error.

matrix of 2^15*101 ~ 3,200,000 elements (doubles) => ~25 Mb of memory

Your code must have a bug somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I modified the code retaining the extended 2^15 data point range for the simulations but keeping only every other element in the waveform vectors I save in the table that I use to store my display data (i.e. vect(2:2:end)) and the problem goes away.  So it still seems like a plotting problem to me.